# doxygen - automatically append text for when a page was last edited?

Tags: doxygen

Is it possible to get doxygen (http://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) to automatically add some text to each generated page that states when the page was last modified due to a code (or comment) change?

Thanks.

Comment: No idea why this got downvoted. Questions don't have to be long to be useful.  Have expanded my comment into an answer as I think this is a relevant topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of anything in Doxygen that can track the *modification* datetime of individual files. There are plenty of ways that pages can be stamped with their generation datetime - see `$date` and `HTML_TIMESTAMP` in [the config section of the manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html), but that's not what you asked.

To track the datetime of changes in individual files I think you need to use a change-related tool rather than a parsing tool.  Options here would include using keywords in your doxygen text (i.e. RCS-style `$DateTime$`) that are replaced by your source code control system, thereby giving you commit times, or possibly using an editor that will do something similar (apparently [Vim does this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time)). Alternatively you could write some form of script to do something similar immediately ahead of you running Doxygen.

On a point of process, it's probably better practice to to manage version marking with a version control system and leave Doxygen operating more like a compiler; otherwise you'll get conflicts/confusion between the two systems.

Comment: Some interesting ideas, thanks. :) I thought that this might be the case.